# Exclude removed objects from list counting?

Tags: unity

I want to count the number of objects on my list. But because I remove and add, my script keep count those empty elements.

update: This happen when I destroy the object when it inside the collider. This object does not get out from "OnTriggerExit2D".

```
public List<GameObject> Sorts;
public List<GameObject> ItemsInside;
public int NumSorts, NumItems;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    NumSorts = Sorts.Count;
    NumItems = ItemsInside.Count; // it doesn't give correct number 

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Sort"))
    {
        Sorts.Add(other.transform.gameObject);

    }
    if (other.transform.name == ("GameItem"))
    {
        ItemsInside.Add(other.transform.gameObject);

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D otherOut)
{

    if (otherOut.CompareTag("Sort"))
    {
        Sorts.Remove(otherOut.transform.gameObject);
    }
    if (otherOut.transform.name == ("GameItem"))
    {
        ItemsInside.Remove(otherOut.transform.gameObject);
    }


}
```

Comment: "my script keep count those empty elements" You have mis-diagnosed this problem. `List.Remove()` does not leave an "empty element" behind. What do you see in the contents of your list in the inspector at a time when it's showing the wrong count? Have you accumulated two copies of the same object? Step through your game to see where the unwanted items first appear.

Comment: So, why it shows "Missing (GameObject)" message after destroy object in my scene? Here is an [image](https://i.postimg.cc/HsDrgbjw/gff.png).

Comment: That's destruction, not removal. I've just performed a test, and OnTriggerExit2D is called correctly when Destroy()ing an object, and the object is successfully removed from the list. You may need to show us some additional scripts in your project for us to be able to reproduce this problem. Try to recreate the issue in a new, empty project, and walk us through every script and every step of scene setup you need to cause the issue.

Comment: Strange!! I have problem with Unity now. lagging and can't run it!! I will check it again tomorrow. Thank you DMG.